# google apps script return row value in a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made this Apps script code:

```
    function myFunction() {  
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]

      var f = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();   
      var values = [   [ f ] ];

      var range = sheet.getRange(4,4); 

      range.setValues(values);
    }
```

And the purpose is to return in the cell `D4` the number of the row of the `activecell`. But everytime I try, it returns me the value "1" instead.

Comment: I have tried your code and a few variations and it appears getActiveCell and getActiveRange are always returning the cell at 1,1. There may be a bug within the API. I will do more tests and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known bug of the Spreadsheet API: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3496

I have found a workaround, but you need to hard code the sheet name:

```
function myFunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      //var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var active = sheet.getActiveCell();

      var f = active.getRowIndex();
      var values = [   [ f ] ];

      var range = sheet.getRange(4,4);

      range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works perfectly. What i need really is to convert this vba code if you can give me some hints.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, that is not really the way this site works. You have asked a specific question and I gave you a working answer. You should try to convert your code by yourself, and ask questions if you face specific issues. thanks :)